# TypeError: getch() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python-2.7

I have this piece of code
i want that if anything is entered other than 1,2,3,4 to take input once again

```
import msvcrt
answer = msvcrt.getch()
while answer not in ['1','2','3','4']:
    answer = msvcrt.getch('Enter a valid option (1,2,3,4):  ')
```

entering anything that is not in the list gives this Error:

```
TypeError: getch() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

but I dont know why its giving me this error tho
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error text is self explanatory. In the second line you called getch correctly:

```
answer = msvcrt.getch()
```

In order for the code to do what it's expected change it to:

```
while answer not in ['1','2','3','4']:
    print 'Enter a valid option (1,2,3,4):  '
    answer = msvcrt.getch()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message means exactly what it says: `msvcrt.getch()` is a function that takes no arguments.

You called it with one argument here:

```
answer = msvcrt.getch('Enter a valid option (1,2,3,4):  ')
```

If you want to print a prompt, then use a separate `print` call first.

Answer (score 0):

This line believes you are trying to pass a value to `getch` which is not allowed.

```
answer = msvcrt.getch('Enter a valid option (1,2,3,4):  ')
```

documentation:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html

While your first use of getch is fine, the second use will throw an error.